# send temperature from Arduino to browser (webserver)

Tags: javascript, arduino, ethernet, temperature

I'm using the ethernet shield, with the TinyWebServer lib
I want to send a value (temperature) from from arduino to my browser. (I can read the index file)
here is the part of the arduino code. ("20" is a value just to try if it works)

```
 TinyWebServer::PathHandler handlers[] = {
  {"/", TinyWebServer::GET, &index_handler},
  {"/" "*", TinyWebServer::GET, &file_handler},
  {"/TEMP" "*", TinyWebServer::GET, &temp_handler },
  {NULL},
};

 boolean temp_handler(TinyWebServer& web_server) {
  web_server.send_error_code(200);
  web_server.send_content_type("text/plain");
  web_server.end_headers();
  Client& client = web_server.get_client();
  int temp=20;
  client.println(temp);
  return temp;
}
```

And here is the part of the HTML code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

//temperatura
function temp() {
    var temperatura;
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/TEMP",
            dataType: "text",
        success: temperatura 
       });
    document.write(success);
         };
</script>
</head>
<body>
Temperatura:
<script type="text/javascript">
temp(); 
</script>
°C
</div>
</body>
```

What's wrong with my code, why I can't see the value ("20")?

Comment: You're thoroughly mis-using `$.ajax`.

Comment: can you tell me what's wrong with the $.ajax code?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/